# Test the non-signaling principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, faster-than-light, causality, locality

Has the non-signaling principle in quantum  mechanics been tested experimentally?

Comment: It would be helpful to define what you mean by "non-signaling principle". I can guess, but it would be better to spell it out.

Comment: Do you mean the [no-communication theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-communication_theorem)?

Comment: @DanielSank No, Danny "non-signaling principle" shouldn't be spelled out. It's a standard expression in QM. It's the famous NO-GO principle that we cannot use entanglements for faster-than-light transmission. (My warm regards!)

Comment: @Sofia: Surprising after seven years of experimental quantum mechanics that I've *never* heard that stated in any kind of authoritative way. Note the +3 on my comment.

Comment: @DanielSank : Danny what is "authoritative way"? My English is far less than yours. I am just telling you that so they call it, not "no-communication", as Hypnos says, but "no-signaling". Why so? I don't know, but so it is. If you get into [quant-ph](http://arxiv.org/find), you'll see.

Comment: @user36125 , very well, but what you want to say with this?

Comment: @Hypnosifl No, no-communication theorem is not what I am looking for, which is one of the well-known theorems. I am looking for experimental references, Please my re-edited question.

Comment: @user36125 : why are you displeased? This expression is very good. It says that whatever one of the experimenters does, the other one won't know from statistics on entanglements. But also, it speaks strictly of statistics, i.e. *counting particles*. A more down-to-earth expression is not known to me. However, one can ask whether there can be other experiments, based on something else.

Comment: Ironic that after @Sofia claimed the request to spell this out was unnecessary that the OP states her interpretation of the phrase is wrong. Another request now to spell out exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The rigorous answer is that experimentally you can prove that something **exists**, not that something **doesn't exist**. We proved that the electron exist, because we found it. But about the non-signaling, we can do *one* type experiment, *two* types, three, etc. And if none of the three experiments transmits FTL (faster-than-light), can we conclude that no type of experiment whatsoever, would transmit FTL?

Only theoretically we can prove the non-signaling, experimentally we can test one more type of experiment, and one more type, etc.

And, theoretically, it was proved. Abner Shimony proved that whatever unitary transformation would lice do on her particle, no change would result on Bob's reduced matrix. Since then, this proof was done for **less restrictive** transformations.

Now, let me tell you the bottom line. In order to obtain FTL transmission we need a **non-unitary** transformation. Not **any** non-unitary transformation, but one of the type realized in the experiment done by Herzog, Rarity, Weinfurter and Zeilinger, PRL 72, 629. But the nature gives us such transformations with *so low probabilities* that we can't exploit them. Bob cannot know when did occur with Alice's particle the non-unitary transformation.

Bottom line, it was proved by A. Peres that FTL transmission implies re-writing the past.

Answer (score 0):

The non-signaling principle stems from the fact that in our Universe the past cannot be re-written. In fact, a Universe in which the past can be re-written cannot exist, it is self-contradictory. Faster-than-light communication appears in some frame of coordinates as sending information backward in time.

Comment: Time rewriting censorship actually only bounds signals to travel inside the past cone of their source, you need at least two FTL operations to result in a time rewriting, which means that this is implicitly assuming that FTL operations must always be composable

Comment: Dear people, I get comments and questions about the "non-signaling" but they are incomplete. Look: "I read the reference paper more carefully (PRL 72, 629, 1994). Could you please elaborate a bit o..." On what do you want me to ellaborate?

Comment: Why post this as a second answer rather than an edit to the first?